# QUnit Async AJAX Unit Test

Tags: jquery, ajax, qunit

I'm trying to write a bunch of unit tests for all of my different ajax request states (Complete, Error, Success), my main issue is that only my first request test fires.  If I remove the first test, then the second test will fire.  Any idea?  I figure since they are asynchronous, they should fire at the same time....

```
module("AJAX Request");

asyncTest("request_data_success", 1, function () {
 $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/104949285507985198959/",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    async: false,
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        ok(true, "Success");
        start();
    }
 });
});

asyncTest("request_data_failure", 1, function () {
 $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/104949285507985198959/",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    async: false,
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ok(textStatus, "Error Message = " + errorThrown);
        start();
    }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async: false` doesn't work with `dataType: 'jsonp'`

This is mentioned briefly in the [docs for async](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).